# iOS Device Crash -- No Simulator Crash

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, testflight

I am using TestFlight for testing my app. On the simulator, the app does not crash. On all iOS devices though, it crashes at a particular instance. TestFlight is not catching the crash data and sending it to me.

When I run the app directly from Xcode into the device, it does not crash! When I retrieved the crash log from the device and used `atos` with the dSYM to find the crash data, I got the following data that's not really useful or a proper stack trace:

```
__destroy_helper_block_ (in TipnTag) (CategoryViewController.m:53)

-[TipsCel setImgMap:] (in TipnTag) (TipsCel.h:34)
-[PlacesGeoCoder geocodingSucceded] (in TipnTag) (PlacesGeoCoder.m:38)
-[TipnTagViewController viewWillAppear:] (in TipnTag) (TipnTagViewController.m:115)

-[TipnTagViewController viewWillAppear:]_block_invoke_0 (in TipnTag) (TipnTagViewController.m:81)
-[TipnTagViewController .cxx_destruct] (in TipnTag) (TipnTagViewController.m:19)

-[PlacesGeoCoder initWithDelegate:] (in TipnTag) (PlacesGeoCoder.m:20)
-[GooglePlacesParser parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:] (in TipnTag) (GooglePlacesParser.m:188)
-[GooglePlacesParser parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:] (in TipnTag) (GooglePlacesParser.m:118)
-[AddComment AddComment:]_block_invoke_078 (in TipnTag) (AddComment.m:88)

-[SearchTips LoadQuestions] (in TipnTag) (SearchTips.m:94)
-[TipsCel setImgMap:] (in TipnTag) (TipsCel.h:34)

-[TipnTagViewController viewDidLoad] (in TipnTag) (TipnTagViewController.m:176)

-[SearchTips LoadQuestions] (in TipnTag) (SearchTips.m:82)
-[TipsCel setImgMap:] (in TipnTag) (TipsCel.h:34)
[TipnTagViewController viewWillAppear:]_block_invoke_0 (in TipnTag) (TipnTagViewController.m:90)
```

Regular stack traces usually have more useful data and are more rigorous.  This is just telling me that something is crashing at `setImgMap` on line 34 at TipsCel.h (which really has no `setImgMap` at all there).

Any thoughts / guidance on how to debug/fix this?

Comment: Is there any variable named `imgMap` in your project?

Comment: @ACB yeah of course. Nothing special though its a button with targets added to it. Why would it crash on a device and not on the simulator?

Comment: The answer is in this method geocodingSucceded. Check it. Also check if `imgMap` is a variable declared in `TipsCel` or not.

Comment: @ACB Hmm that method never gets called. imgMap is an IBOutlet.